# Are perpetual magnetic motors a scam?

Tags: electromagnetism, perpetual-motion

I read articles and watched [videos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KxK7Yf3aSzI&) and more [videos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n2F_PepgyKk) where people say they've built perpetual magnetic motors.

I do not see any proof that this can work and also I do not see proof that it is wrong. I'm not really into physics. People tend to say this is scum and cannot happen. Can somebody explain what is wrong in the first video?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2167/2451

Comment: It is impossible, since environment takes away energy, and energy is conserved. These are all scams without any doubt.

Comment: Scams. The worst is that the videos of such "free energy sources" clearly show a lot of noise being produced, i.e a lot of energy being lost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid to say that unless we're considering incredibly cold superconductors (which have been known to sustain currents for years), none of these devices work. The first video offers instruction on building all manner of green devices including solar power generators and I'm not sure If it even claims to be a perpetual motion machine. I mention the other devices because if it was perpetual energy generation, you wouldn't need anything else!

The second video makes all manner of strange claims, including room temperature superconductivity which would be defying quite a few laws of Physics and regardless, isn't something proven by a one and a half minute video of something spinning. As well as saying that the Earth's orbit around the Sun is perpetual which isn't true as the orbit is continually changing - it just lasts a *long* time. As for electrons orbiting an atom, this just isn't true either. It's an old idea that was used in teasing out conceptually what was happening, but nearly all of the predictions based on this are wrong.

Hope that helps, please feel free to ask any more questions.