# Is magnetic wheel possible?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, perpetual-motion

I once tried to make a magnetic wheel using different shaped magnets and placing them in different orientations and of different shapes.But it did rotate making a small angle ie it didnt rotate even a full circle.I still think I can do this with strongest magnet  with a magnet with required north south pole arrangement or with two opposite poles neutral and other two opposite poles working.Is this feasible?I require some suggestions please.

Comment: This sounds like another 'free energy device'- if it is, then the answer is no.

Comment: Magnetic energy is used here sir,how is it impossible?

Comment: Where is it used?

Comment: Not found sir,sadly.I think this is because of unavailability of the superstrong magnets with two of its opposite sides neutral and two working.

Comment: Can you rephrase what they are claiming? *what* is possible?

Comment: You can search in google about the working principle of this wheel in google.But some say its perpetual motion machine,a youtube video shows its working.But after I tried this,i knew wheel is not possible in this way.During its rotation two opposite poles should only work and the other two poles should be neutral with comparatively very small surface area.I havent tried this due to lack of resources and also I dont know how to neutralize poles of magnet.

Comment: Free energy/perp. motion devices are scams. They do not and cannot work. Read up on the first and second law of thermodynamics. this is also interesting: http://www.kilty.com/pmotion.htm

Comment: May be you are talking about perpetual motion machine of first and second kind  sir?Can you tell me that,can I get two opposite sides neutral superstrong magnets with negligible neutral side`s surface area?I want to try my way before failing.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2167/2451 and links therein.

Comment: What do you mean by "neutralize poles of magnet?"  Are you talking about a magnetic monopole?

Comment: I just want two opposite sides of a magnet with considerable surface area and the other two opposite sides neutral with comparatively small surface area.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

What you are describing sounds like an electric motor with only permanent magnets. This is one of the most used approaches for people who try to build a perpetum mobile. But energy can neither be created or destroyed, so it has to come from somewhere.

So this eternal engine might work if you in some way harvest the vibrations of the magnet.  Like thermal vibrations and maybe even quantum vibrations. When I think of it doesn't every object have a certain vibration? These vibrations might then be transferred to the magnetic field and a changing oscillating magnetic field can do some work. Maybe a magnetic crystal would do this best, as all the small atomic magnets might get harmonic oscillations which makes the whole magnetic field oscillate as one. That reminds me of Earths core which probably is such a crystal magnet. The weak geomagnetic field has some oscillations, but vibrations are also caused by the impact of charged particles from the solar wind.

So my suggestion is trying to harvest vibrations in some way, then you can make your wheel spin. If you still will try out the traditional approach I suggest to experiment with putting permanent magnets permanently pole to pole so they counteract, and play with the angles, they will then create quite different fields and not so many has tried out this approach, but again it will only work if you accidentally manage to harvest some power from some source. Good thing energy is all around us and everything that is.

Comment: Thank you Enos oye,im new to this site.I will try my way with yours.

Comment: This scheme will not work as the second law of thermodynamics forbids the extraction of energy from an equilibrium system. To "harvest the vibrations" (at equilibrium) you at least need another heat bath and then it is much easier to harvest the energy thermoelectrically or by a Stirling engine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this an other candidates to perpetum mobile is that all these   systems in uses forces that can be written as a potential. If that is the case they will reach a configuration of minimal energy in which, if put in that position at rest, the system will remain at rest. Yo cannot extranct any work from the system

Answer (score -1):

lesser quantity attracted to greater quantity following path of least resistance.  Magnetic fields are not curved except when following many iron filings, since through iron is less resistance than through space.  A north pole attracts a south pole not in a curved line, but the magnet attracts straight to the other magnet.  Fact: can't create energy from nothing... Theory:  there could be a way to turn a magnetic wheel with proper shielding (on and off - mechanical or electrical -- either would take energy) at the right time.  The energy comes from the magnetic attraction/repulsion.  This is not anymore zero energy as a water wheel or a wind generator.  One side of the wheel must catch or be moved by while the other side of the wheel either does not become influenced as in a water wheel or be less influenced on one side than the other as in a horizontal wind generator (example: weather station {VAAVUD Wind Meter }.  Keep up the work and this would not be a free energy device anymore than solar, water, or wind.

Comment: This could use some formatting and possible a bit more detailed physics explanation.