# Magnet motor free energy generator

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, perpetual-motion

Is it possible to run a fan without electricity? like the one show on this website?

http://free-energi.com/index.php?a=2

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2167/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

As [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion) clearly lays out, the concept of a free energy generator - a machine that will perform work on external systems eternally and without needing external intervention - is inconsistent with either the first or the second law of thermodynamics.  There exist, as yet, no credible and reproducible experiments that shed any type of doubt on either of these two laws, nor any credible or reproducible experiments that demonstrate any kind of perpetual motion machine or free energy generator.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the (rather funny) disclaimer on that site:

> This website presents a serious risk of damaging your self-confidence in case you decide to take any content of this website seriously and try unsuccesfully to utilize it any usefull way.

"Free energy" is not possible due to energy conservation.

Comment: "The devices, described within this website, may be illegal in some countries. Observe your local legislation before doing anything." Do they mean the laws of physics?

Answer (score 0):

Reading in the disclaimer section:

> The authors of this website are not responsible for ridicule, which can cause yourself by an effort to reproduce the devices described here.
>
> The authors of this website are not responsible for the time you may waste reading this website. They are also not responsible for the time you may waste by trying unsuccessfully to reproduce any object described hereby.
>
> This website presents a serious risk of damaging your self-confidence in case you decide to take any content of this website seriously and try unsuccessfully to utilize it any useful way.

I think it says everything. Still it is a nice exercise try to find out how the pictures where obtained. Talking about the fan, air was probably blown from outside, in the portable version there is probably a small battery in the corners under the tape.